# How to load the weights of the first few layers of Convolutional Neural Network in Keras and delete the pre-trained model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I have a pretrained model trained in Keras.

I am trying to use that model in another task, but I don't need all the layers, but only the first 4 conv layers.

I have the model saved in "keras_pretrained_model.h5"

Is it possible to initialize the first 4 conv layers of the new model using the weights of the first 4 conv layers of the pretrained model from the '.h5' file?

Is loading the whole pretrained model first always necessary??

The pretrained model actually takes up a lot of space and I am not sure how to delete the pretrained model after I initializing the new model with the weights. As far as I understand, using `tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` will clear the new model created along with the old one.

So, my question is

1. Is there any way to initialize the weights in the new model layers without loading the whole pretrained model?
2. If I have to load the whole pretrained model, how to delete only the pretrained model without harming the new model in any way?

Answer (score 0):

I have thought of two processes

1. If the names of the layers of the first 4 layers of the new model is same as the 4 layers in the pre-trained model, then
   `new_model.load_weights(path_to_old_model_file, by_name = True)`
2. If the names don't mathc, then we can do layer wise weight initialization by taking the weights from the corresponding layers in the old model h5 file and setting the weights using `set_weights()` method.
   I have written a code, which I have uploaded to github, [here](https://github.com/sadimanna/keras_load_pretrained_model_without_loading_the_model).

I would be very grateful, if anyone seeing this gives a feedback on this!!